# jQuery Validate: how do I validate based on other field's value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form.  If a select field is set to the first option, then I have two radio groups that must be set.  If the select is set to any other value, they don't have to be set.

The select:

```
<div class="field grid_10">
    <label for="severityId" class="grid_3">Severity</label>
    <div class="grid_6"> 
        <form:select id="severityId" path="severityId" items="${severityList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="title" />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"> </div>
</div>
```

The validation:

```
 function validate_eventReviewForm() {      

    jQuery('#review-edit-form').validate ({
        rules: {
            sampleWasLost: {required: {
                depends: function(element){
                    return $("#severityId").val() == 1
                }}},
            backupSampleAvail: {
                depends: function(element){
                    return $("#severityId").val() == 1
                }}
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, I tried two separate ways to get jQuery to mark it as required.  Neither one works.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your second script is causing an error which is causing the validation to fail

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#review-edit-form').validate({
    rules: {
      sampleWasLost: {
        required: {
          depends: function(element) {
            return $("#severityId").val() == 1
          }
        }
      },
      backupSampleAvail: {
        required: {
          depends: function(element) {
            return $("#severityId").val() == 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js"></script>


<form id="review-edit-form" method="post" action="">
  <select name="severityId" id="severityId">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="sampleWasLost" value="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="sampleWasLost" value="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="sampleWasLost" value="3" />
  <input type="radio" name="sampleWasLost" value="4" />
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="backupSampleAvail" value="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="backupSampleAvail" value="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="backupSampleAvail" value="3" />
  <input type="radio" name="backupSampleAvail" value="4" />
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: That's what I get for trusting teh jQuery documentation: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#code Thank you!

Comment: @GregDougherty, I see nothing in the documentation that caused you to write the broken code.  Arun P Johny, maybe you could expand the answer to provide more detail about how the OP's code was broken... like explaining that `.validate()` is only used for initializing the plugin and would not be called inside another function like the OP was doing.